# Light is not illuminating

Tags: light, error

I'm quite new to this but as I move the light around, it's not illuminating anything.

The light is shown as below. As you can see it's all dark.

[image]

The file is https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1gUYerWWGkvm6UbAs4rW070Er9fzo4c-Y

Thanks you guys in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Light size is too big that's why you are not able to see it if you reduce it to 1 m or closer to it don't increase the size too much as this fades the intensity of light
so if you wan't to cover the more region try increasing the size in spot shape that is above blend that is increasing the area by increasing angle
and another reason is you world environment is too bright so that's why effect of light is not visible.
and then just press "z" to open pie menu and switch to rendered view

Answer (score 0):

Press Z and set shading to Rendered / Look Dev? It should then display your materials and the lighting they receive.

Comment: Thanks guys! That works!